# How can in get an array of Shopify product ids to return a correct response in GraphQl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, graphql, shopify

I am trying to get a correct response from a graphQl query of an array of products. My goal is to take this array of products and sort it from news to oldest published date. I have tested it with a simple array of two product gids but i am receiving an error response.

`Parse error on "gid://shopify/Product/777229615129" (STRING) at [1, 16]`

here is my code:

```
const token = 'Storefront API custom app token';

const queryPage = JSON.stringify({
  query:`query ($ids : ["gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/777229615129","gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/7772297068794"]) {
    nodes(ids:$ids){
      ... on Product{
        id
        title
      }
    }
  }`
});
const storefrontSettingsPage = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://"+shopname+".myshopify.com/api/2022-07/graphql.json",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": queryPage,
};
$.ajax(storefrontSettingsPage).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I am still learning to use graphQl, what am I doing wrong.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Still not one hundred percent sure on how it works, but was able to makes this work using a different type of writing style, and using variables.

```js
const token = 'Storefront API custom app token';

$.ajax({
  url: "https://"+shopname+".myshopify.com/api/2022-07/graphql.json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  type:'POST',
  headers:{
    "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    query:`query ($ids : [ID!]!) {
      nodes(ids:$ids){
        ... on Product{
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }`,
    variables: {
      ids:["gid://shopify/Product/7772296151290","gid://shopify/Product/7772297068794"]
    }
  }),
}).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```